# Prevent ajax call on empty spaces typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I have been working with `typeahead.js` and loading data using `BloodHound remote` option.

Everthing is working as expected except that when i enter `only spaces` in `textbox` typeahead still `sends ajax call`.

I want to know if there is way to `prevent ajax call` if there are `only spaces` in textbox. I am looking for similar behavior like `trim`.

Here is my code. I have tried to use `prepare` function but with no luck.

```
var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('ProductID', 'ProductName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
              url: urlVar + "LoadAllProductByProductName/%QUERY",
              wildcard: '%QUERY',

            },
    sufficient: 3,
   });

const $tagsInput = $('.txtProductName')
$tagsInput.typeahead({
   minLength: 3,
   source: dataSource,
   hint: false,
   highlight: true,
   isBlankString: false
   },
   {
      limit: 10,
      source: dataSource,
      name: 'dataSource',
      display: function (item) {
         return item.ProductName
      },
      suggestion: function (data) {
         return '<div>' + data.ProductName + '–' + data.ProductID + '</div>'
      },

});
```

Comment: why is it a problem to send the call when there are spaces? Presumably the user will just get no results.

Comment: I want to avoid network trip.

Comment: give that a network trip is generated every single time the user types _anything_ where there are more than 3 characters, and the chances of a user actually typing 3 empty spaces (they aren't likely to think it will return anything!), you might go to a lot of effort and reduce your network traffic by 0.0001%. Just saying it seems a bit pointless. But if you really want to, you could create a custom function for the `source` attribute and prevent the request from going ahead at that point based on the search terms (and just return an empty array). The typeahead docs show the method signature

Comment: Look this [example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#default-suggestions)

Answer (score 4):

I would try attaching a keyUp event to the text box to perform the filtration:

```
$tagsInput.keyup(function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/  */, ' ');
    });
```

That will fire after the second space, which should mitigate the undesired behavior unless there are non-space characters in the field, as well.

Comment: i think this is the possible way

Comment: Even if it works, it's not the sort of solution I'm looking for. If you're sure there is no idiomatic way to do it, I prefer that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `remote` property has a `prepare` function which you can use the handle this change prior to the call going over the wire.

As an example:

```
function createBloodHoundConfig(options) {
    return {
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        identify: options.identify,
        sufficient: 8,
        remote: {
            url: options.url,
            prepare: function (query, settings) {
                settings.url = settings.url.replace("{q}", query.trim());
                return settings;
            }
        },
    };
}
```

Note that in this case you do not supply the `wildcard` property, as it is effectively a shorthand for doing token replacement.

Comment: This doesn't prevent the call. It simply `trim`s what is searched for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this?

```
prepare: function (query, settings) {
                    var word = $.trim(query);
                    if(word){
                        settings.url = "/search?q=" + 
                       word;
                        return settings;
                    }
                },
```